# Identifying comments from the same source

Tags: php, comments

What ideas can I try to find out if comments are from the same users. The assumption is that people will try to cheat and post comments under multiple pseudonyms. My environment is PHP and I can install any third party library as needed. What should I do to minimize this risk and identify comments posted by the same source (as much as possible).

Comment: What do you mean? Does your site let non registered users post comments and you want to identify these people when they come back so they don't post again?

Comment: no matter what you do, if more than one person is logging in to your site from the same computer, you will get a false positive.

Comment: i think he wants to make sure the same person isn't making multiple accounts.

Comment: you can't log IPs because multiple users on a network behind a proxy could have the same IP. you could use cookies to id a user, but it is fairly circumventable, and is a false positive if more than one person uses the same computer.

Comment: @dqhendricks and @spinon, I'm flexible and understand the risk of false positives. Some implementation is better than nothing.

Comment: @park Not sure I agree with the "some implementation is better than nothing", especially if it's the wrong implementation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the user by logging the IP address upon the users first comment, then checking to see if that IP address exists in the database on any subsequent comments. However, this data can be spoofed so it isn't fail-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can realistically do this is to enforce a user login for comments, as IP addresses aren't sufficiently unique and cookies are trivial to erase at the client end.

That said, there is of course nothing to stop people creating multiple users accounts with a variety of email addresses (gmail/Yahoo, etc.) so you'll want to create your own tools/admin view so you can trivially check IP addresses if you suspect people are still misbehaving. (A tool for your armoury if nothing else.)  On a similar basis, you could also log the browser agent header.